# Oracle to PostgreSQL translate

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am migrating Oracle DLL to PostgreSQL, I am having an issue translate the following piece of code to PostgreSQL

```
-- Generate ID using sequence and trigger
CREATE SEQUENCE partner_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER partner_seq_tr
 BEFORE INSERT ON partner FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (NEW.idPartner IS NULL)
BEGIN
 SELECT partner_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.idPartner FROM DUAL;
END;
/
-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX partner_idxName ON partner (Name);
-- COMMIT;
```

Comment: Are you trying to have a ```idPartner``` have a sequence attached to it?  If so how about setting the ```DEFAULT``` value for ```idPartner``` to ```nextval('partner_seq')```?

Comment: Hello Maria did you look ora2pg utility ?
http://ora2pg.darold.net/ Else ...
From what I understand, you want to create a column in auto increment. It is precisely a native implementation under PostgreSQL ....
Maybe this could help: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/ Have fun

Comment: No, interesting I take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need a trigger in Postgres for that. Simply declare the column as

```
idpartner integer generated always as identity
```

And Postgres will use the (automatically created) sequence automatically if the column is not specified as a target column in the INSERT statement.

Alternatively, if you really want a trigger:

```
create sequence partner_seq;

create function assign_partner_id()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin 
  if new.idpartner is null then 
     new.idpartner := nextval('partner_seq');
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger partner_seq_trg
  before on partner insert on each row
  execute procedure assign_partner_id();
```

Comment: I am working with spring boot app,that's why i need to created triggers .. constantly getting ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist. Adding trigger as you suggested has a syntax error at -------- insert on each row    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "row"

Comment: The joys of obfuscation layers... Regarding the syntax error: see my edit.